# Преобразование Фурье в Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy, фурье

Есть DataFrame примерно такого содержания:

```
Time     Data
95114    1012.0
96078    1108.0
97033    1132.0
98015    1076.0
...
```

Состоит из 100 строк, где:

- Time - время измерения в микросекундах
- Data - измеряемое значение.

Мне необходимо найти ДПФ этой зависимости. Все бы ничего, только частота измерения непостоянна. Она немного плывет со временем случайным образом. Т.е. мои потуги в духе:

```
xf = fftfreq(len(df['Time']),1000) # 1000 взята как примерный период измерений
i = xf > 0
yf = fft(df['Data'])
```

Дают немного неожиданный результат. Я так понимаю, что дело в частоте. Как правильно ее искать? Интерполировать свой дискретный ряд и потом уже находить его ДПФ?

В итоге мне нужно будет найти площадь между определенными частотами спектра.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться методом [DataFrame.resample()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html), чтобы преобразовать DataFrame во временной ряд с единым интервалом (в качестве единого интервала возьмем *средний* интервал между замерами в микросекундах) и после этого интерполировать недостающие значения.

Для этого надо конвертировать `df.Time` в `datetime` dtype и установить этот столбец в качестве индекса:

```
In [62]: freq = int(df['Time'].diff().mean()) # средняя частота измерения в микросекундах

In [63]: freq
Out[63]: 967

In [64]: df = (df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.pop('Time'), unit='us'))
                 .resample('{}U'.format(freq))
                 .mean()
                 .interpolate())

In [65]: df
Out[65]:
                              Data
Time
1970-01-01 00:00:00.094766  1012.0
1970-01-01 00:00:00.095733  1108.0
1970-01-01 00:00:00.096700  1132.0
1970-01-01 00:00:00.097667  1076.0
```

После этого можно попробовать воспользоваться преобразованиями Фурье.